# All Pairs Shortest Path Under Weight

Tags: graph, counting, weighted

Let be G a given undirected simple graph, with edge-weights w. Does there exist an algorithm with time complexity O((n+m)log^*(n+m)) that counts the number of node pairs (u,v) for which there exists a path from u to v with total weight under some given constant W? Looking for either an algorithm or a proof that no such algorithm exists.

I’ve tried union find + DFS yet it doesn’t seem that will only use up to n+m calls to Find/Union... I’ve also tried dis-proving the existence on an algorithm by solving APSP with time complexity lower than the lower bound, yet to no avail.

Comment: Could you provide the code and data that covers exactly what you are asking, and where it’s going wrong?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the question. The problem is a theoretical one, not really related to any specific code or data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Successfully shown no such algorithm exists:

Assume by contradiction that such an algorithm exists.

Let G be a given undirected un-weighted graph, we’ll compute the diameter of the graph as follows:

1. Assign weight 1 to every edge on the graph. Thus the weighted diameter is equal to un-weighted diameter.
2. We find that the diameter of the graph is bounded by m
3. Perform a binary search using the algorithm to find the diameter of the graph (check for each value whether or not the count returns zero).

Overall, we find the diameter of G in O((n+m)log(n)log*(n+m)). The current best algorithms for finding a graph diameter are O(min(nm, ~n^2.4)). Thus, at the very least, if this algorithm succeeded then the time complexity of computing a diameter would decrease dramatically. Not entirely a proof, but good enough for the purpose I needed it for.